# Automatically open applications at start up in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, startup

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my pi 2 with Xubuntu as my GUI and I am trying to figure out how to start application automatically after login. I have tried several different methods (listed below) and non have worked.

I am trying to start Xastir and Direwolf for now and plan on doing more in the future.

The first thing I tried was adding `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` at the bottom of my direwolf.desktop and xastir.desktop files using `nano`. direwolf.desktop and xastir.desktop are short scripts that launch the two programs from the desktop. Modifying these files yielded no success.

For my second attempt, I typed `gnome-session-properties` into terminal which opened the startup application program. I then clicked "add" once for direwolf and once for xastir. From here I entered in the applications' respective names into the "name" space and entered `lxterm-hold-title "Dire Wolf" -bg white -e "/usr/local/bin/direwolf"` in the command section for direwolf and `gnome-terminal -t Xastir_Terminal --geometry=160x48 -x` for xastir. I pulled direwolf's command from the `Exec=` part of the direwolf.desktop file. The Xastir command was pulled from the `Exec=` from [here](http://xastir.org/pipermail/xastir/2014-July/022287.html). On reboot, neither application opens.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I open more applications automatically at startup in the future? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Did you try it this way](http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.de/2011/12/add-application-to-xfcexubuntu-session.html) ?

> Add Application to startup

- Open 'Settings Manager'
- Select 'Session and Startup'
- On the 'Application Autostart' click on the 'Add' button

Comment: This did the trick! For anyone who is curious on what to put in the "command" bar, I typed the same command you would in terminal to start the intended program. For me it was simply `xastir` and `dirwolf`, the names of the applications.